# excel formula, updating value and checking

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm really new to excel but I have programming experience. I am trying to do the following function, but I dont really know how I could declare a variable and change it as I go. This would be a pseudocode. This is a hypothetical scenario to what I am trying to achieve:

```
newName = ""

if (change == "yes")
newName = origName
column3 = newName

if (origName contains newName && change != "yes")
column3 = newName
else
column3 = origName
```

**What I mean by contain is that for example, if origName is "paper towel" and newName is "paper" then origName contains newName because of "paper"

So basically there are three columns containing strings: origName, change and Column3

I want to create a program that keeps writing the same in origName in Column3 UNTIL change equals "YES". When this happens, I want to store the origName (in which changes equals "YES") into a variable name newName. After that, I want to keep checking the following rows if the origName contains the same name as newName, and write newName into Column3 if it does. It will keep checking rows until it gets to another row in which change will equal YES and newName will be set to the corresponding origName, and keep the process going. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can do this with a formula. Is VBA a necessity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I got the logic you're looking for:

1. In `C2`, put the formula `=A2`.
2. In `C3`, put the formula `=IF(B3="Yes",A3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,A3)),C2,A3))` and drag down.

[image]